# Prevent Non-NPC Sims From Buying at my Business

Tags: the-sims-2

I play sims 2 open for business on a shared computer which makes running a business difficult because I have to try very hard to prevent other peoples sims from buying expensive things which they can't afford or don't need (Which the respective player will be displeased with), this can also have adverse affects on the running of my business as well as their sims wallets. Is there a way to ensure only NPCs or non-user-made sims visit my business? Or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Whenever a player switches to another 'created' sim, the sim they switched from automaticly acts like a NPC. As far as I know, it's not possible to tell them not to buy anything.

Comment: you could try locking them in their house? (remove all doors). but as mentioned they become NPCs when you stop playing, so they might still be able to escape.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this.

The first way is with a hack. There are a couple out there, but [No Playable Shoppers](http://www.moreawesomethanyou.com/smf/index.php/topic,3419.0.html) from More Awesome Than You is probably the simplest and most trustworthy.

The second is to avoid mixing your playable sims with anyone else's by making a unique neighborhood for each player. The base game comes with three neighborhoods already set up: Pleasantview, Strange Town, and Veronaville. Sims from Pleasantview do not meet sims from Strange Town or Veronaville, so you and the person you share a PC with could each pick a neighborhood or create a custom neighborhood to keep the sims separated from each other. If you have already started sharing a neighborhood, or if you both want to use the same neighborhood, there are ways of copying the neighborhood files (basically, your saved game) to create duplicate neighborhoods. Or take the easier route and export your sims, then import into a new neighborhood.

The downside to the multiple neighborhood approach is it doesn't work if you yourself have more than one playable house, for example if you make two different families. Only a hack will work in that case. But if you don't want to use hacks, separate neighborhoods is the best option.